# File Load Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I was debugging in the .Net framework source code suddenly when I stepped into a file of theirs, visual studio 2010 raised this error:

> File Load:
> Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file XXX, Saving the file will not preserve the original file contents.

when I click OK, the file is marked as unsaved, and when I try to save it, it says that the file is locked, but I can overwrite the file. I don't know what this message means.

And why is now, not the first time when visual studio downloaded the file from the Symbol server?

Comment: Are you using the "debug assemblies" feature of .Net Reflector?

Comment: @chibacity probably the MS reference source since he talked about downloads from the symbol server

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yeah, I thought the OP would realise if it was that though as you have to manually set it up. Coming to think of if, I don't think Reflector PRO downloads debug symbols for Framework stuff.

Comment: guys, I just enabled the (Enable .Net Framework source stepping) feature, in visual studio 2010, and it did the rest for me.

Comment: I got this error once from doing a Replace operation with Qt. It "corrupted" all of my copyright symbols.

Answer (score 16):

I started to get this error after switching on (for test purposes) the new setting "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in the recent Windows 10 Spring 2018 update.

The message would then appear for every file that has non-ascii characters (German Umlauts mostly in my case) and had not been stored as UTF8 before.

Short-time fix: Revert the setting to not use UTF-8 as the "Current language for non-unicode programs", but use a language with the special characters that are used in the source files.

Long-time fix: Convert all your soure files to UTF-8.

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this issue by changing my "Language for non-Unicode programs" setting to "English (United States)".
If you are using Windows 10, you can find it in "Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Region -> Administrative".

[image: Screenshot of the Region Settings dialog in Windows]

Comment: Thank you, this workaround helps me. I've lost Russian language for my non-Unicode apps support but it's ok. The main thing is that the Visual Studio is working without this issue.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Windows 10, you can find it in `Control Panel` -> `Clock, Language, and Region` -> `Region` -> `Administrative`. From Language for non-Unicode programs, select `"Select system locale"`.

Uncheck box `"Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"`. Press ok. You will be prompted to restart windows - do it.

After that if you're developer - you might encounter compile errors in Visual studio like this:

`error C2855: command-line option "source-charset" inconsistent with precompiled header`

Just rebuild whole project and problem will disappear.

Comment: Incredible. And I was thinking that this was Visual studio's problem, but apparently this is some windows new feature. Bit annoying that needs to restart window, but gosh - I got rid of this warning permanently. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

I've just faced the same problem. It needs to open a file a save it back again. I guess some kinda tool that could do that in a batch will do the trick.

upd: Actually seems that's not helping... Looking for another solution

upd2: Resaving a file actually helps, but you have to disable this option:

**Debugging\General\Require source files to exactly match the original version**

Comment: i got this error in vs 2013 when i pasted  html code from web and it used this symbol ♦    , if you need utf-8 encoding in your page check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797686/best-way-to-encode-degree-celsius-symbol-into-web-page), hope helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same problem. it seems vs2010 is trying to read the source file using wrong encoding. I open the file with editpad and convert it to utf-8, and it becomes ok.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was
[this beta settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyKu4.png)
that was causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

well i used notepad++ and edited every file in the project 
in the end of every file there is NullNullNullNull line remove it and click ctrl+S  do this to all files it will help i know it helped me

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your computer encoding setting (as I'm both working on French and Chinese environnement), Here is a way to convert your soure files to UTF-8 encoding using VS Code :

1. Open the file with VS Code
2. Find the encoding botton at the bottom right (usually says UTF-8)
3. Clik on it and selecte reopen wiht encoding, then selecte the first one (automatic recommandation)
4. Now you can see the garbled characters gone
5. Clik again on the encoding botton and this time selecte save wiht encoding, then selecte UTF-8
6. Save file

Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the SVN *.tmpl template file for version numbers, and it contains the (c) copyright symbol.  VS 2010 complains about this when it generates the AssemblyInfo.cs file from the AssemblyInfo.tmpl file.

So I replaced the copyright symbol with "(c)" and the error message went away.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is that I found the page giving error 
"Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file _PartialLogin.cshtml , Saving the file will not preserve the original file contents."

I opened _PartialLogin.cshtml in a different editor than VS 2017 ( I used Notepad++) click >Encoding< on the menu bar then choose >Encode in UTF-8<
then save the file.
Its done.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems sometimes with windows 10 options.
Solution: Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative -> Change System Locale -> Uncheck the box (Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support)