# Best way to encode Degree Celsius symbol into web page?

Tags: html, symbols

How should I encode special characters into web pages? For instance I need this symbol ℃, which I used just by copying and pasting the character as I can see it now. This worked for the desktop browsers I checked with and also on iPad and iPhone but nothing is displayed on a Blackberry I used for testing. Is there a standard best practice for this?

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2103/browsertest.htm

Comment: Is there a standard thinking about what to use, UTF-8 vs Hex or another format? Thanks

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't understand your question at first. I believe UTF-8 is generally preferred. As for the symbol itself, I usually just do the degree sign followed by a capital C, like so: °C. I am not sure whether or not this is better or worse than your solution. I guess the biggest difference is the letter spacing between the two characters.

Comment: I think its necessary for this symbol to do it your way. Thanks

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Try to replace it with `&deg;`, and also to set the charset to utf-8, as Martin suggests.

`&deg;C` will get you something like this:

[image: Degrees Celsius]

Comment: Best answer, in my opinion

Comment: That's Perfect!

Comment: for some reason that will result to Â°C

Answer (score 38):

If you really want to use the DEGREE CELSIUS character “℃”, then copy and paste is OK, provided that your document is UTF-8 encoded and declared as such in HTTP headers. Using the character reference `&#x2103;` would work equally well, and would work independently of character encoding, but the source would be much less readable.

The problem with Blackberry is most probably a font issue. I don’t know about fonts on Blackberry, but the font repertoire might be limited. There’s nothing you can do about this in HTML, but you can use CSS, possibly with `@font face`.

But there is seldom any reason to use the DEGREE CELSIUS. It is a compatibility character, included in Unicode due to its use in East Asian writing. The Unicode Standard explicitly says in [Chapter 15](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/ch15.pdf) (section 15.2, page 497):

“In normal use, it is better to represent degrees Celsius “°C” with a sequence of U+00B0
degree sign + U+0043 latin capital letter c, rather than U+2103 degree celsius.”

The degree sign “°” can be entered in many ways, including the entity reference `°, but normally it is best to insert it as a character, via copy and paste or otherwise. On Windows, you can use Alt 0176.

Caveat: Some browsers may treat the degree sign as allowing a line break after it even when no space intervenes, putting “°” and the following “C” on separate lines. There are [different ways to prevent this](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html). A simple and effective method is this: `<nobr>42 °C</nobr>`.

Comment: One of the best answers I have read, with direct quote from key source. Awesome!!

Comment: Why so complicated at all? The degree celsius is on the top left side of my keyboard just press it?

Comment: @Pascal, what keyboard might that be?

Comment: Use style="white-space: nowrap" instead of <nobr>.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

Comment: Inspired by @Pascal: alt code: ```alt+0176```

Answer (score 14):

Using [sup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) on the letter "o" and a capital "C"

```html
<sup>o</sup>C
```

Should work in all browsers and IE6+

Comment: The letter «o» is not the degree symbol, but it might *look* like the degree symbol for humans. This is a hack and will be confusing for computers to understand - like screen readers and search engines.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why this hasn't come up yet but why don't you use `&#8451;` (℃) or `&#8457;` (℉) for Celsius and Fahrenheit respectively!

Comment: What do they look like?

Comment: @Matthieu see here: https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%26%238457%3B and https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%26%238451%3B

Answer (score 5):

Add a metatag to your header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

This expands the amount of characters you can use.

Comment: In HTML5 you can just use `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` I believe.

Comment: In my case, this was the real solution.  VS2015 behaves according to what "Content-Type" meta tag says.

Comment: Adding this resolved an issue for me where a `°` was being rendered as `Â°` in an `img` alt tag where the source image was missing.

Answer (score 0):

1. The degree sign belongs to the *number*, and not to the "C". You can regard the degree sign as a number symbol, just like the minus sign.
2. There shall *not* be any space between the digits and the degree sign.
3. There *shall* be a non-breaking space between the degree sign and the "C".

Comment: Could you give a source of those assertions?

Answer (score 0):

If using Java-JSP, What worked for me is to paste below in JSP page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```