# Making second word smaller

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering how I could make the ° smaller, this is what I tried:

```js
$(function() {
  var weather = {};
  weather.temperature = '24';

  $(".wthr").html(weather.temperature + "&deg;");
});
```

```css
.wthr::last-word {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="clock wthr anim04c"><span></span></li>
```

However it did not work, how can I make the ° smaller?

Comment: anyway you are using `.html` right? you can use `<sup>` tag for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797686/best-way-to-encode-degree-celsius-symbol-into-web-page

Comment: @SK. the linked question is not what the OP is looking for

Comment: @AravindS using `<sup>` will not make the font smaller, will it?

Comment: @ochi OP want to make  the ° smaller?

Comment: I know, so your suggestion does nothing of the sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might put the `°` in a `::after` and give it your desired font size:

```js
$(".wthr").html("10");
```

```css
.wthr::after {
  font-size: 60%;
  content: "°";
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="clock wthr anim04c"><span class="temp"></span></li>
```

If you don't always need the degree symbol on `.wthr`, then you can add a class on `.wthr` as well:

```js
$(".wthr")
  .html("10")
  .addClass('deg');
```

```css
.deg::after {
  font-size: 60%;
  content: "°";
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="clock wthr anim04c"><span class="temp"></span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your ° in a span and reduce the font of that.  As in,

```js
$(function() {
  var weather = {};
  weather.temperature = '24';

  $(".wthr").html(weather.temperature + "<span>&deg;</span>");
});
```

```css
.wthr span {
  font-size: 50%;
  vertical-align: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="clock wthr anim04c"><span></span></li>
```

UPDATED: edited as suggested by @Sangram

Comment: i am not able to see the degree in your preview? anything missing?

Comment: Add `vertical-align: 7px;` and it retains the vertical position as well

Comment: @SangramNandkhile edited answer, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the ° in a span and giving it a class or setting the style inline.

```
$(".wthr").html(weather.temperature +<span style="font-size:50;">"&deg;"</span>);
```

Comment: Your code will fail as you are not matching/pairing your quotes correctly.