# How to show symbol ℃ instead of the word?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple page in my Wordpress side and  want to use symbol ℃ in it.

I've changed  the code related to link(see below):

https://www.alt-codes.net/degree_sign_alt_code.php

```
//code adjusted as below

title:{
          //initial text with a word Celsius        
             text: "Average low winter temperature  in  Celsius"

              //I've changed code as below:
             // text: "Average low winter temperature  in  '&#8451'"
  },
```

..but  output shows extra characters instead of symbol ℃.

How to show symbol ℃ instead of word 'Celsius'?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to encode Degree Celsius symbol into web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797686/best-way-to-encode-degree-celsius-symbol-into-web-page)

Comment: Make sure the page is saved and served as UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: I've used  the previous  answer as below but it show no output at all
//doesn't work as below:
              // text: "Average low winter temperature  in  &deg;C

Comment: I've changed as suggested(see below):

text: "Average low winter temperature  in  "&#8451;"

but there no output.. page become empty..So, I go back to the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may escape it with Unicode, use **\u2103**

```
title: {
   text: "Average low winter temperature \u2103" 
   // expected Average low winter temperature ℃
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the HTML code for your requirement

```
<p>I will display &#176;C</p>
```

Also check other ways to display the degree symbol [here](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/degree-sign/)

Comment: I added as below but gotbthe empty page..

//<p>I will display &#176;C</p>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need

```
 <p>I will display &#x2103;</p>
```