# Why does Visual Studio show Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTERS (U+FFFD) in my C# file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I downloaded the project from bitbucket. When I download [I get errors like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760943/character-code-of-unknown-character-character-e-g-square-or-question-mark-romb) and I see some characters are not decoded incorrectly.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File Load Some bytes have been replaced with the Unicode substitution character while loading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305923/file-load-some-bytes-have-been-replaced-with-the-unicode-substitution-character)

Comment: How did you download the file from bitbucket? If it was through their web interface then you won't get `git`'s built-in automatic platform encoding/text/etc handling... or the file was improperly saved in the first place.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/957502/file-is-corrupted-when-pusing-to-git-repo-on-bitbucket

Comment: just dump the bytes in the file or check with a hex editor and you'll see. It has been corrupted before coming to VS